# Why is it called "time space" as in fourier transform

Tags: fourier-transform

When talking about Fourier transform for image processing, we often call the original image formed by pixels in the "time space".

I find it is difficult to understand it. why is it called the time space, where is time coming from?

I can understand if it is called screen space and image space. but why is it time space?

Comment: I think this may be an historical analogy to signals analysis in which the dual spaces are time/frequency. I guess if the independent variable is $t$ (time) you can loosely say you are working in the "time domain" or "time space."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original formulation of Fourier series was to take a signal, which is to say a function of amplitude values over time, and represent it as a combination of sinusoids, which is to say a function of amplitude values over a range of frequencies. So you would consider the original signal to be $f(t)$, defined over the domain of time $t$, and the Fourier transform $\mathcal{F(f)} = F(T)$, defined over the domain of frequency $T$.

Obviously in the case of image processing the analogy isn't great, since you now have a 2-dimensional "time domain", but it seems like the language has stuck despite that.